# Use WordPress shortcode to add <meta> tags

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm writing a simple WordPress plugin that uses shortcode. I want the page that contains the shortcode to have specific `<meta>` tags. Is this possible? And if so, is there an elegant way to do it?

I know that I can add `<meta>` tags with the `wp_head` hook, but I want the meta tag content to match a string produced by the plugin. I could move all the code into the header, but then I'm not sure how to reference it later from the shortcode. In other words, when I declare a variable in the `<head>` with a filter, it's not available to the class methods that I'm calling with the shortcode.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

A nice solution was proposed in which the handler function for the shortcode adds the action to the wp_head hook:

```
add_shortcode('fakeshortcode', 'fakeshortcode_handler');
function fakeshortcode_handler() {

    function add_meta_tags() {
        //echo stuff here that will go in the head
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta_tags');
}
```

This is swell, but the problem is that wp_head happens BEFORE the shortcode gets parsed and adds the action (so nothing gets added to the head with the code above ALONE). To make it work, I borrowed the solution in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17513/append-stylesheet-via-shortcode). It's basically a function that "looks ahead" into the post and sees if there is any shortcode coming. If it is, then IT adds the `add_action('wp_head'...`.

EDIT:
I removed my follow-up question about how to pass the variable.
It's a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573344/how-can-i-pass-a-variable-wordpress-shortcode).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**First attempt (don't use this... see the 'edit' below)**:

First, you need to set your shortcode with something like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'metashortcode', 'metashortcode_addshortcode' );
```

Then, you'll create the function in which you'll have to add a hook to `wp_head` with something like that:

```
function metashortcode_addshortcode() {
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'metashortcode_setmeta' );
}
```

Then, you'll define what you want to do in the `wp_head` :

```
function metashortcode_setmeta() {
    echo '<meta name="key" content="value">';
}
```

Adding the shortcode `[metashortcode]` should add your meta data as needed.  The code was provided only to help you understand how to make it happen.  It was not fully tested.

**Edit : The previous code was just a concept and cannot work because of the execution order.  Here is a working example that will get the expected result:**

```
// Function to hook to "the_posts" (just edit the two variables)
function metashortcode_mycode( $posts ) {
  $shortcode = 'metashortcode';
  $callback_function = 'metashortcode_setmeta';

  return metashortcode_shortcode_to_wphead( $posts, $shortcode, $callback_function );
}

// To execute when shortcode is found
function metashortcode_setmeta() {
    echo '<meta name="key" content="value">';
}

// look for shortcode in the content and apply expected behaviour (don't edit!)
function metashortcode_shortcode_to_wphead( $posts, $shortcode, $callback_function ) {
  if ( empty( $posts ) )
    return $posts;

  $found = false;
  foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    if ( stripos( $post->post_content, '[' . $shortcode ) !== false ) {
      add_shortcode( $shortcode, '__return_empty_string' );
      $found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if ( $found )
    add_action( 'wp_head', $callback_function );

  return $posts;
}

// Instead of creating a shortcode, hook to the_posts
add_action( 'the_posts', 'metashortcode_mycode' );
```

Enjoy!

Comment: That's cool. I didn't realize that the shortcode got parsed BEFORE the wp_head actions happened. I'll give this a try right away. If you're right I'm sure it'll solve my problem nicely!

Comment: My suspicion was correct. wp_head actions are triggered BEFORE the shortcode gets parsed. So this solution doesn't work exactly as described. HOWEVER, the approach can be modified... [see my update above]

Comment: Sorry Emerson, I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  It is NOT executed before.  Therefore, I edited my solution to make it work properly.

Comment: I think we were editing the same post at the same time... Unfortunately, I think I've overwritten your changes. Sorry!

Comment: This looks great! Do you have any advice about how to pass the variable? In my project, the $shortcode variable changes. You'll see how I'm trying to globalize it in my code, but it's not working.

Comment: In case this question wasn't clear, my plugin is basically structured as follows. 1. It defines a class which generates a unique string. 2. It defines shortcode which can be used to add the string into the <head>. I'm not having any luck getting that string variable into the header. I think the only way to do it is with messy global variables.

Comment: In the 'metashortcode_mycode', you could call the database,get all your shortcodes and values for your meta and loop in there.  Also, you could change the function parameter to an array and check all your shortcodes at once.  That is another whole topic!

Comment: By the way, I think you should close this question and ask another one.  By asking a new question in the same thread, it makes the answer given and the title of this question useless to other people.  Mark this one as "closed" and start a new question to avoid confusion.  Please.

Comment: Good idea. The new question about passing the argument is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573344/how-can-i-pass-a-variable-wordpress-shortcode

Comment: Thanks for the nice idea! One comment: you should not use '__return_true', but rather '__return_empty_string'. When using '__return_true' one gets a "1" in the post content :D.

Answer (score 2):

This post was written a long time ago, but I think using the `has_shortcode` function is a another good solution:

```
function add_meta_tags() {
    global $post;
    if ( has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'YOUR-SHORTCODE' ) ) {
    
    //echo stuff here that will go in the head
    
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta_tags');
```