# How can I pass a variable wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a Wordpress plugin which dynamically creates a string.
I want to insert this string in a meta tag using the `wp_head` hook.

My plugin works as follows: I define a shortcode whose handler function declares an `add_action(...` that adds a special `<meta>` tag into the header.

This works, BUT...

My only problem is that I can't figure out how to pass the variable containing the string to get printed into the head. The variable isn't defined, even though I globalize it in my plugin.

```
//INSIDE MY PLUGIN...

global $head_string;

function initialize_my_plugin_class() {
    $head_string = "<meta>bla bla bla</meta>";
}

function add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta_tags' ) //this is slightly oversimplified
                                                 //the execution order of wp_head makes
                                                 //the real code a bit more complicated
                                                 //for the purposes of this question let's
                                                 //pretend it's like this.

function add_meta_tags() {
    echo $head_string
}
```

The result works, EXCEPT that the `$head_string` variable is empty. So it prints an empty meta tag. (I know everything else works because I can change `add_meta_tags()` to do something like `echo "FAKE META TAG";` and it shows up where it should in the header.)

So what's wrong with what I'm doing? I think it must involve variable scope, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting $head_string as global inside your functions.

Comment: I've tried a couple variations of globalizing that variable (because I'm a confused by the PHP documentation on globals!). Is your suggestion to set it as global ONLY inside the function(s), or in addition to the `global` declaration that's outside?

Comment: I'd try it in additional to the original global declaration

Comment: Not sure if it's "right" but it's workin'. I'm specifying `global` every time I reference that variable (inside and outside of the function). Using globals like this makes me a feel yucky...

Comment: Yeah it's definitely not the best way to use globals, but I've had similar issues with Wordpress in the past and this was the only way I was able to get them to work unfortunately.